# Is there a way to setup a mail account that will only send OUTBOUND mail after it gets Approved by a user?

Tags: exchange-2007

I have MS Exchange Server 2007 and I would like to set up a users mailbox to have the following functions:

1. All OUTBOUND mail sent form that account goes into a QUEUE.
2. When someone "Approves" the users mail the mail will be sent.

How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an appropriate moderation functionality in Exchange 2007. It exists in Exchange 2010.

Comment: What about how to quarantine outbound mail for an account, like the spam quarantine?

Comment: If you'll utilize smarthost on the Exchange server, it would be up to the smarthost to setup this scenario.